# Class Libraries, MVC, and Data Annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and am unsure about proper design.

I have class objects which I use in a variety of applications. I have taken the approach to write a custom view model class so that I can have access to properties in all of these objects and have strong typing. Without re-typing all my class code in the view model is there any way to have the properties in these objects validated using data annotation? Please let me know if my approach and design is all wrong.

```
[Required]        
public User user = new User("username");
//User has lots properites and methods, could i validate inside my class code?
```

//What I'd like to avoid is putting the following stuff in my custom view model class, //since I already have a class library with this stuff:

```
public class User
{

    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string prop3 { get; set; }

    public User(string token)
    {
        SetUser(token);
    }


    public void SetUser(string token)
    {
        this.prop1 = "this";
        this.prop2 = "this2";
        this.prop3 = "this3";

    }
```

============
Good to know I can, but I'm stumbling on some issues. In my view I have:       @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.user.prop1)

I put the data annotation stuff in my class domain. When it renders it does show the annoations.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field prop1 must be a string with a maximum length of 5." data-val-length-max="5" data-val-required="The prop1 field is required." id="user_prop1" name="user.prop1" type="text" value="somevalue" />
```

but when I go to my controller the parameter is null. I think because the name is user.prop1. I tried a textbox where i specified the name attribute and yet my controller still couldn't get a value for my parameter.

====================

```
            @model TrainingCalendar.Models.Training

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Signup";
            }

            <h2>Signup</h2>

            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmSignup", "Training", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Training</legend>
                    <p>
                    @Html.Label("date", Model.SpecifiedCourse.strClassDate)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    @Html.Label("time", Model.SpecifiedCourse.Time)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    @Html.Label("instructor", Model.SpecifiedCourse.Instructor)
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    @Html.Hidden("id", Model.SpecifiedCourse.ID)
                    </p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop1)</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop1)</td>
                            <td style="color:Red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop1)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop2)</td>
                            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop2)</td>
                            <td style="color:Red">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.ApplicationUser.prop2)</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>   
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            }

            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
```

===================

```
            public ActionResult ConfirmSignup(
                        int id,
                        string prop1,
                        string prop2)
                    {
                        SignUpForClass();
                    return View();
                }
```

Comment: What parameter is null?  Are you using model binding?

Comment: I'm attempting right now to create a custom model binder. I haven't been able to get it to work. My custom view model class has a generic list, 2 strings, 1 int, and 2 objects of my own creation: user and trainingcourse. The user object has a method which sets the values however, I have moved this out of the constructor. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your POST (no pun intended) action method?

Comment: Here is the simplified version of my code. I've resorted to slapping my forehead. I managed to get the validation to work when I created a new View, and selected a strongly-typed view to my model. Then after some testing and enhancements the client validation stopped working. Since MVC Asp.net does so much for you I can't track down what changed. Trying to create another new view has not solved the problem. And prop1 and prop2 parameters are coming up null.

Comment: I noticed that you are using some individual properties instead of your view model as the parameters to your action.  If your view model was called Training then your signature should be: public ActionResult ConfirmSignup(Training trainingObject){ // code here }.  Then the trainingObject object will be populated by the view with model binding.  You can have other parameters that can be passed by various means, but model binding allows you to recreate the view model as a parameter to your POST action, assuming that the View is strongly typed to the view model.

Comment: Learning a lot about MVC. Thanks for your continued interest. My training object is passed but my user object inside is null. I have the EditorFor html helpers so I would think that my model is properly bound with my user information. Is it that I'm passing a new Training object from my view and my user object inside hasn't been set? I can get what I want using the following, but as I'm learning MVC I want to take advantage of the model binding. Values is FormValues type: values.GetValue("ApplicationUser.prop1").AttemptedValue;

Comment: It sounds as if everything is correct from the MVC aspect of things.  The one thing that I just noticed was that you are instantiating a user in your view model: public User user = new User("username");  This should just be a getter/setter: public User User { get; set; }.  And your User object should have a default public constructor and any properties that you are setting using model binding must have public getters/setters.  The model binding mechanism requires a default public constructor and public getters/setters for the object it is creating.

Comment: Thanks so much. My model object has a value when passed. This is much better than looping through form values.

Comment: Fantastic, congratulations and welcome to the world of MVC3 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely you can have the data annotation attributes on your class code.  If you're encapsulating the class in your view model, populated the properties of the encapsulated class in your view.  During the validation process the class members will be validated against the data annotation attributes that you specify in the class declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been trying to do as you recommend and I'm running into some issues. I put the additional information above in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled along this too and what I ended up doing (I don't know if it is the best or most correct) is too have data annotations that effect primarily the database in the DOM of my class library, such as MaxLength, Required, etc, and then in my view models I have the data annotations that relate primarily to validation such as Regular Expression, Date Time Formats, Max Values, or Max Lengths. In this way I keep the the roles of the two different aspects of the system separate. The View Model is a translation from my DOM to a format that my View can work with and my DOM is specifically for defining what the data should look like in the database.

Comment: Good to know I can, but I'm stumbling on some issues. In my view I have: